# how can I change the settings (e.g., port) used by "yesod devel"?

Tags: yesod

I know I can put port numbers in `config/settings.yml` but they seem to be ignored when running `yesod devel`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You want to use the `-p` option. More generally:

```
$ yesod devel --help
Usage: yesod devel [-d|--disable-api] [-s|--success-hook COMMAND]
                   [-f|--failure-hook COMMAND] [-t|--event-timeout N]
                   [-b|--builddir ARG] [-i|--ignore DIR]
                   [-e|--extra-cabal-arg ARG] [-p|--port N]
                   [-x|--proxy-timeout N] [-n|--disable-reverse-proxy]
                   [-c|--interrupt-only]
  Run project with the devel server

Available options:
  -d,--disable-api         Disable fast GHC API rebuilding
  -s,--success-hook COMMAND
                           Run COMMAND after rebuild succeeds
  -f,--failure-hook COMMAND
                           Run COMMAND when rebuild fails
  -t,--event-timeout N     Force rescan of files every N seconds
  -b,--builddir ARG        Set custom cabal build directory, default `dist'
  -i,--ignore DIR          ignore file changes in DIR
  -e,--extra-cabal-arg ARG pass extra argument ARG to cabal
  -p,--port N              Devel server listening port
  -x,--proxy-timeout N     Devel server timeout before returning 'not ready'
                           message (in seconds, 0 for none)
  -n,--disable-reverse-proxy
                           Disable reverse proxy
  -c,--interrupt-only      Disable exiting when enter is pressed
```

Comment: can I set `approot` as well?

Comment: You should be able to set that from inside config/settings.yml. The suffix `:3000` will be replaced by whatever argument you've given to `yesod devel` for `-p`.