# Change Yesod port number

Tags: haskell, yesod

From [Deploying Yesod web app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33657566/deploying-yesod-web-app/33658396#33658396), I could copy the executable, static, and config file to run Yesod as a standalone web server. This is the directory structure.

```
├── config
│   ├── client_session_key.aes
│   ├── favicon.ico
│   ├── keter.yml
│   ├── models
│   ├── robots.txt
│   ├── routes
│   ├── settings.yml
│   ├── sqlite.yml
│   └── test-settings.yml
├── my-project
├── my-project.sqlite3
└── static
```

I tried to use different port by changing config/settings.yml

```
port:           "_env:PORT:3002"
approot:        "_env:APPROOT:http://localhost:3002"
```

However, the app is still accessible with port 3000. Even I removed the settings.yml, but there was no error message.

The way to change the port was from changing the environment variables `export PORT=3002` from https://github.com/yesodweb/yesod/wiki/Configuration#overriding-configuration-values-with-environment-variables, but I it's not what I can use.

For development I can use `stack exec -- yesod devel -p 3003` ([how can I change the settings (e.g., port) used by "yesod devel"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24485158/how-can-i-change-the-settings-e-g-port-used-by-yesod-devel)), but I don't seem to use the `-p` option with the Yesod executable (my-project).

Why the executable does not (seem to) load `config/settings`? How to setup to use different port in Yesod web app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like that the setting file should be in the same directory as the executable.

I copied config/settings.yml in current directory, then run the `./my_project settings.yml`, now it uses the 3002 port correctly.

I have some hints from https://github.com/yesodweb/yesod/issues/474